# how to login multiple user in same browser using django

Tags: django, django-sessions

I am create a application where admin and customer login same browser.
I read many blog not able not fix my problem. As Django use session based login.

I am facing issue while logout my admin then my customer automatic logout. maybe session based functionally

```
My admin LoginView and Logoutview:

class AdminLoginView(SuccessMessageMixin,LoginView):
   
    authentication_form = LoginForm
    template_name = 'login.html'
    redirect_field_name = reverse_lazy('admin_panel:dashboard')
    redirect_authenticated_user = False
    success_message = '%(username)s login Successfully !'

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            # messages.info(self.request, f"{self.request.user.firstname} is already Logged In")
            return redirect('/admin/dashboard/')
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self):
        url = self.get_redirect_url()
        LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('admin_panel:dashboard')
        return url or resolve_url(LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)





class LogoutView(LogoutView):
    """
      Log out the user and display the 'You are logged out' message.
    """
    next_page = "/admin/login"

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO,'Successfully logged out.')
        return response
```

I have implemented customer based login & logout

```
def LoginView(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data["username"]
        password = form.cleaned_data["password"]
        remember_me = form.cleaned_data["remember_me"]
        user = User.objects.get(email=username)
        if user and user.check_password(password):
            if user.is_active:
                if remember_me == False:
                    request.session.set_expiry(0)
                request.session['user_id'] = user.id
                request.session['username'] = user.email
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
            else:
                context = {'auth_error': "You're account is disabled"}
                return render(request, 'forntend-signin.html', context )
        else:
            context = {
                'auth_error': 'username and password incorrect'
            }
            return render(request, 'forntend-signin.html', context)
    else:
        context = {
            "form": form
        }
    return render(request, 'forntend-signin.html', context)


def customer_logout(request):
    try:
        if request.session['username']:
            del request.session['user_id']
            del request.session['username']
        else:
            del request.session['user_id']
    except KeyError:
        HttpResponseRedirect("/")
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

Please suggest me how to fix this issue.

If there any documentation available the please share.

Comment: Are admin and customer separated by URL or domain in any way?

Comment: Here is my admin [login](http://35.154.229.152/admin/login/) and Here is my customer [login](http://35.154.229.152/login)